# Paginación html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código

```
        VIDEOS
    ======================================-->
    <div class="row" id="videos">

<hr style="border-color: #eabe12">

<h1 class="text-center text-info"><b style="color: #eabe12;">VIDEO GALLERY</b></h1>

<hr style="border-color: #eabe12">

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <video controls width="100%">
                    <source src="controlpanel/views/videos/video920.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <video controls width="100%">
                    <source src="controlpanel/views/videos/video814.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <video controls width="100%">
                    <source src="controlpanel/views/videos/video864.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <video controls width="100%">
                    <source src="controlpanel/views/videos/video561.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>  <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
            <ul class='pagination'>
                <li><a style='background-color: #eabe12; color: black; border-color: #eabe12;' href='?pag=1' aria-label='Previous'><span style='color:black;' aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span></a></li><li class='active'><a style='background-color: #eabe12; color: black; border-color: #eabe12;' href='?pag=1' >1</a></li><li><a style='background-color: #eabe12; color: black; border-color: #eabe12;' href='?pag=1' aria-label='Next' ><span style='color:black; aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span></a></li></ul></div>
```

Es un ejemplo de una paginación. Lo que necesito sabe es que si hay alguna forma en que al hacer clic en los enlaces de la paginación (atrás o adelante o en el número), este se quede en el div llamado video, ya que como esta implementado , cuando doy clic en cualquiera de los enlaces, este no se queda en el div video, sino que me recarga la pagina y me ubica en la parte superior de mi pagina web.

Espero que me colaboren. Gracias

Comment: Para la paginación, la programaste o usaste algún complemento?

Comment: Lo programé desde bootstrap, no usé ningún complemento